# Is definable $\emptyset$-definable?

Tags: terminology, definition, model-theory

A set $A$ is $X$-definable in an $L$-structure $\mathcal{M}$ with a domain $M$ iff there are an $L$ formula $\phi(a,\bar x)$ and $\bar x \in X^n$ such that $A=\{a \in M^m | \mathcal{M} \models \phi(a,\bar x)\}$.

Often people say that a set $A$ is just definable. Do they mean that $A$ is $\emptyset$-definable or that $A$ is $M$-definable?

Comment: Depends on the context, really. In model theory, I believe the usual meaning is $\varnothing$-definable. In set theory it usually means $M$-definable (e.g. when constructing $L$ we take the "definable" subsets at each step), because we *usually* care less about the parameters.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I hoped for an absolute answer. If nobody protests for a few days, I will accept yours.

Comment: I don't think there is a usual meaning even in model theory. In my experience, usually you would infer from the context whether or not you allow parameters in the definition. When it truly matters, it is usually stressed one way or another.

Comment: Also, you definition of definable set seems a little off to me. A definable set is the set of all elements satisfying a given formula. What you describe here I would hardly call definable. $\bigvee$-definable, maybe. Instead, it should probably read more or less "there is a formula $\varphi(a,x)$ and $\bar x \in X^n$ such that $A=\{a\in M^m\mid \mathcal M\models \varphi(a,\bar x)\}$".

Comment: @tomasz Thank you for the correction on the misplacement of the existential quantifier. Edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A set $D$ is $A$-definable in $M$ if there is parameter-free formula $\varphi(z,x)$ and a tuple $a\in A^{|z|}$ such that $D=\{b\in M^{|x|}\ :\ M\models\varphi(a,b)\}$. (Were $|\cdot|$ denotes the length of the tuple.)

The following is useful to know (it justifies the notation used above):

[i] My writing $a\in A^{|x|}$ is overscrupulous. Usually it is agreed that $a\in A$ stands for $a\in A^{|a|}$ (it has become very common to use the same notations for tuple and for elements).

[ii] Definable stands for $M$-definable unless the author explicitly says the contrary.

[iii] Sometimes $0$-definable is used for $\varnothing$-definable.

[iv] In 90% of the scientific articles, a structure is denoted with the same symbol used for its domain.

Comment: I don't think I entirely agree about the second point. When we allow parameters from the monster model, we don't call the sets definable, but rather externally definable (unless we are talking about subsets of *the same* monster model, of course). I'm also not convinced that the convention that definable stands for definable with parameters is all that universal. The rest, I agree with.

Comment: @tomasz Indeed, in [ii] I was talking about subsets of the monster models. (I deleted the sentence as it may generate confusion.)

Answer (score 1):

We can see :

- Katrin Tent & Martin Ziegler, [A Course in Model Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=D9sClsdErEsC&pg=PA9) (2012), page 4 :

> Let $B$ be a subset of $A$ [the *domain* of the $L$-*structure* $\mathfrak A$]. By considering every element of $B$ as a new constant, we obtain the new language
>
> $$L(B) = L \cup B$$

Aand the $L(B)$-structure

> $$\mathfrak A_B = (\mathfrak A, b)_{b∈B}.$$

Then see page 9 :

> [A formula] $\varphi(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ defines an $n$-ary relation
>
> $$\varphi(\mathfrak A) = \{ \overline a \mid \mathfrak A \vDash \varphi[\overline a] \}$$
>
> on $A$ [the *domain* of $\mathfrak A$], the *realisation set* of $\varphi$. Such realisation sets are called $0$-*definable subsets* of $A^n$, or $0$-definable relations.
>
> Let $B$ be a subset of $A$. A $B$-*definable* subset of $\mathfrak A$ is a set of the form $\varphi(\mathfrak A)$ for an $L(B)$-formula $\varphi(x)$. We also say that $\varphi$ (and $\varphi(\mathfrak A)$) are defined *over* $B$ and that the set $\varphi(\mathfrak A)$ is defined by $\varphi$. Often we don’t explicitly specify a parameter set $B$ and just talk about *definable* subsets. A $0$-definable set is definable over the empty set.
> structure they define the same set.

Comment: The first part (N.B. not the second) of Tent & Ziegler seems to be copy-pasted from Chang & Keisler, a 50 years old book. Hence notation is a bit heavy. In my answer I restate the same with modern notation and mention what are the common assumptions.